# looking for react native video trimer .react-native-video-processing not enough good

Tags: reactjs, video, native, trim

Is there any way to trim video ? I can't find any library for that.
react-native-video-processing not enough good

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more advanced I would suggest taking a look at FFmpegKit: https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit

FFmpegKit provides a lot of powerful tools to manipulate video.